# Use setTimeout with Recursion funtion

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I'm trying to make a slideshow. I peek at some snippets and then try to recreate them without plainly copying.
This is the snippet:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Well, what I do not understand how does the setTimeout works when the function was just called once, and why not to use setInterval outside the function.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can you not use setInterval outside the function?

Comment: Actually this is my doubt. 
When and why should I use the recursion with setTimeout instead a setInterval outside of it.

Comment: It totally depends on you how you code. There's no exact definition of how people are to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last thing `showSlides` does is set a timeout to call itself again after 2 seconds. After that call finishes, it sets another timeout. That will continue forever.

In this case, there wouldn't be a noticeable difference if you used `setInterval`. Both would accomplish the same thing. `setInterval` would be easier to cancel though, which is an advantage.

Be sure to remove the call to `setTimeout` in `showSlides` if you do use `setInterval` though:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
} 

setInterval(showSlides, 2000);
```

To cancel the interval, capture the ID returned by `setInterval` and call `clearTimeout`:

```js
let id = setInterval(showSlides, 2000);
clearTimeout(id); // This will clear and cancel the setInterval
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know why the setTimeout was doing its thing, it was very clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet, It will work!, you need to use setInterval

```
   setInterval(showSlides, 2000);
```

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}


setInterval(showSlides, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="mySlides">Slide 1</div>
<div class="mySlides">Slide 2</div>
<div class="mySlides">Slide 3</div>
<div class="mySlides">Slide 4</div>
<div class="mySlides">Slide 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, both answers were great.